Old cartoon (colour) tv series
This may be from the 60's, I remember to have watched it in the late 80's. I belive the main background colour was yellowish. I think this cartoon is from Eastern Europe.
It is a boy in a farm with a windmill. He has a bird as his company. In each episode the boy had to find a way to solve problems in the farm or to build something new. We could see him thinking (idea lamp above his head), making up some plans and then with some tools (hammer, saw, nails etc) he would make it possible, and the bird would also help.

Is it this one (Pomyslowy Dobromir)?

YES!!!!!!! Thank you very much!!!!  Your help made me very happy ! This is what i was looking for a long time :D

No problem :) Marking it as duplicate, if that's OK
